# Equivariant sheaves on $\mathbb P^1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, kt.k-theory-and-homology, equivariant

Let $K(\mathbb P^1)$ be the Grothendieck group of sheaves on $\mathbb P^1$. I want to show that the map $K^{{\rm PGL}(2)\times \{\pm 1\}}(\mathbb P^1) \to K(\mathbb P^1)$ is not onto. I read somewhere that the class of a vector bundle of odd degree on $\mathbb P^1$ is not equal to the class of a sheaf equivariant under ${\rm PGL}(2)\times \{\pm 1\}$. Could you explain me why this is the case?

Comment: $\operatorname{PGL}(2)\times \{\pm 1\}  $ does not act on $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: @abx Why not? I thought that $PGL(2)$ acts on $\mathbb P^1$ by $(a,b;c,d)(x:y)=((ax+by):(cx+dy))$ and $\{\pm 1\}$ acts on $\mathbb P^1$ by $(x:y) \mapsto (-x:y)$. Since $PGL(2)$ and $\{\pm 1\}$ both act on $\mathbb P^1$, their product also should act on $\mathbb P^1$, no?

Comment: These actions do not commute.

Comment: Besides, the element $(-1,0;0,1) \in \mathrm{PGL}(2)$ acts in the same way as your $-1$.

Comment: Ok, sorry, maybe I misunderstood what the paper says

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain why the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$ does not admit a $\mathrm{PGL}(2)$-equivariant structure. Indeed, if it does, then the vector space
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{O}, \mathcal{O}(1))
$$
would have a structure of a $\mathrm{PGL}(2)$-representation, compatible with the standard $\mathrm{SL}(2)$-representation structure. But this is not true, because the central element $-1 \in \mathrm{SL}(2)$ acts on this space non-trivially.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Sorry, could you explain a little more: why should the ${\rm PGL(2)}$-representation ${\rm Hom}(\mathcal O, \mathcal O(1))$ be compatible with the standard ${\rm SL(2)}$-representation structure?

Comment: Why can't the vector space ${\rm Hom}(\mathcal O, \mathcal O(1))$ be a direct sum of two trivial representations of ${\rm SL}(2)$?

Comment: I think I understand now: if $H^0(\mathcal O(1))$ is a trivial representation of ${\rm SL}(2)$ then it is also a trivial representation of ${\rm PGL}(2)$, so ${\rm PGL}(2)$ fixes every section, and hence every point in every fiber through which there is a section, and on ${\mathbb P}^1$ there is a section of $\mathcal O(1)$ through every point of every fiber of $\mathcal O(1)$.